# How to make a PUT request in Ember?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data, put

I'm new in Ember. I have an application using Ember and Ember-data, with a Rails backend using a Mongo database (Mongoid gem). I want to make a PUT request to update a many-to-many relationship, but I don't know how to: transactions, ajax jQuery function... Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This already exist in ember data https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L351. So just performing a record.save() in a existing record, will do an update, with a request using PUT. Are you using an older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ember Data 1.0 beta 2 and newer simply calling `save()` on a model will trigger a `PUT` request to save changes to your backend. If you are using Rails I recommend using `DS.RESTAdapter`.

Comment: I thought on trying the new version 1.0 of Ember Data after completing my project, because it's necessary to make some changes. The thing is actually I'm making GET and POST requests and they work correctly, but in this PUT request my entity is being sent correctly with all the standard strings attributes and the one-to-many relationship attribute, but is not including the many-to-many relationship attribute, which is an unexpected behaviour... Anyway I'll try with 1.0 version and I'll tell you. Thank you @chopper!